# Show that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\mathrm dx=-\frac1{\alpha^s}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi \alpha)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, polylogarithm

I have come across the following integral while going over [this list](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c737278h1674162_10010_rare_and_irresistible_integrals) (Problem $35$)

> $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\mathrm dx=-\frac1{\alpha^s}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi \alpha)}~~~~s>0, \alpha\in(0,1)$$
> where $\operatorname{Li}_s(x)$ denotes the Polylogarithm Function.

Using the series expansion of $\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\mathrm dx&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{x^{\alpha+1}}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{n^s}\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{x^{\alpha+1}}\mathrm dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-\alpha-1}\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$

One can easily see the problems concerning the convergence of the last integral. Also, I am not even sure whether it is possible to change the order of summation and integration in this case or not.

Another approach is based on an integral representation of $\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)$ so that the given integral becomes

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\mathrm dx&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{x^{\alpha+1}}\left[\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t/(-x)-1}\mathrm dt\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=-\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{x^{\alpha}(e^t+x)}\mathrm dx\mathrm dt\\
\end{align}$$

From hereon, I do not know how to proceed. Since the solution reminds me of Euler's Reflection Formula it might be possible to reshape the integral in terms of the Gamma Function somehow.

> I am asking for a whole evaluation of the given integral. I did not found anything closely related to this question but correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like an application of [Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem), coupled with the reflection formula for the Gamma function.

Comment: @nospoon Is it possible to use this Theorem here? I also thought about a potential connection to the Mellin Transform but hence the $x$-term has the form $x^{-\alpha-1}$ instead of $x^{\alpha-1}$ I do not know whether this possible or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're just one step away: for $b>0$, we have $$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{x^\alpha }(b + x)}}dx}  = {b^{ - \alpha }}\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{ - \alpha }}}}{{1 + x}}dx}  = \frac{{{b^{ - \alpha }}\pi }}{{\sin \alpha \pi }}$$
so
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}dx=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{x^{\alpha}(e^t+x)}dxdt = - \frac{\pi }{{\Gamma (s)\sin \alpha \pi }}\int_0^\infty  {{t^{s - 1}}{e^{ - \alpha t}}dt} $$

---

The series expansion of $\text{Li}_s(-x)$ only converges for $|x| < 1$, so your first method is illegitimate.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I guessed for myself that I went wrong somewhere concerning the convergence of the series expansion. Furhermore I was not aware of this integral identity at the moment. I think it can be shown using the Beta Function hence I remember some kind of identity similiar to this? But nevertheless I am glad you provided an asnwer :)

Answer (score 8):

I have finally figured out how to use [Ramanujans Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) in this case.

> **Ramanujans Master Theorem**
>
> Let $f(x)$ be an analytic function with a MacLaurin Expansion of the form
> $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(k)}{k!}(-x)^k$$then the Mellin Transform of this function is given by
> $$\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)\mathrm dx=\Gamma(s)\phi(-s)$$

Lets get back to the given integral. The series representation of  $\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)$ is given by $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^k}{k^s}$ and therefore, by using the Gamma Function as extension of the factorial, we obtain $\displaystyle\phi(k)=\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{k^s}$. Now applying the Mellin Transform with $s=-\alpha$ yields to

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^{-\alpha-1}\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)\mathrm dx=\Gamma(-\alpha)\phi(\alpha)=\Gamma(-\alpha)\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\alpha^s}$$

This term can be simplified by using Eulers Reflection Formula with $z=\alpha+1$ which finally leads to

$$\frac1{\alpha^s}\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(-\alpha)=\frac1{\alpha^s}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi(\alpha+1))}=-\frac1{\alpha^s}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi\alpha)}$$

Comment: RMT always finds a way... +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

A contour integration approach:

For $s >0$,  $\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-z)$ has a branch cut on $(-\infty, -1]$.

On the upper side of the branch cut, the imaginary part of $\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-x) $ is $-\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(s)}\log^{s-1}(-x)$, while on the lower side of the branch cut, the imaginary part of $\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-x) $ is $\frac{\pi }{\Gamma(s)}\log^{s-1}(-x) $.
(See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Properties) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2883632).)

For the function $\frac{1}{z^{\alpha+1}}$, let's place the branch cut on the positive real axis, and define $\frac{1}{z^{\alpha+1}}$ to be real-valued on the upper side of the branch cut.

Let's then integrate the function $$ f(z) = \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-z)}{z^{\alpha +1}}, \quad ( s>0, \, 0 < \alpha <1),$$  around a double keyhole contour that is deformed around the two branch cuts.

The contour looks like the contour used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1039345).

There are no singularities inside the contour, and the branch points at $z=0$ and $z=-1$ are integrable.

Furthermore, $f(z) \sim  - \frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)} \frac{\ln^{s}(z)}{z^{\alpha +1}} $ as $ |z| \to \infty$ .  (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Asymptotic_expansions).)

Therefore, letting the radii of the two big semicircles go to infinity (and the radii of the two small circles go to zero), we get
$$\begin{align} \oint f(z) \, \mathrm dz &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}} \, \mathrm dx + \int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{\Re \left(\operatorname{Li}_{s}(t) \right) - \frac{\pi i}{\Gamma(s)}\ln^{s-1} (t)}{(te^{\pi i})^{\alpha +1}} \,  (- \mathrm dt) \\ &+ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\Re \left(\operatorname{Li}_{s}(t) \right) + \frac{\pi i}{\Gamma(s)} \ln^{s-1} (t)}{(te^{\pi i})^{\alpha +1}} (-\mathrm dt) \ +\int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-t)}{(te^{2 \pi i})^{\alpha+1}} \, \mathrm dt =0 , \end{align}$$

from which it follows that

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}} \, \mathrm dx  &= \frac{1 }{\Gamma(s)}\frac{ 2 \pi i \, e^{- \pi i (\alpha +1) } }{1-e^{-2 \pi i(\alpha+1)}} \int_{1}^{\infty}  \frac{\ln^{s-1}(t)}{t^{\alpha+1}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\frac{ \pi}{\sin \left(\pi(\alpha +1)\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{s-1}e^{- \alpha u} \, \mathrm du \\ &= -\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\frac{ \pi}{\sin(\pi \alpha)} \frac{1}{\alpha^s}\int_{0}^{\infty} v^{s-1} e^{-v} \, \mathrm d v \\ &= -\frac{ \pi}{\sin(\pi \alpha)} \frac{1}{\alpha^s}. \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x^{a+1}}\mathrm dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{a}}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x}\right)\mathrm dx$$

$$=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{a}}\left(\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(s-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{s-1}(y)}{1+yx}\mathrm  dy\right)\mathrm dx$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(s-1)!}\int_0^1 \ln^{s-1}(y)\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-a}}{1+yx}\mathrm dx\right)\mathrm dy$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(s-1)!}\int_0^1 \ln^{s-1}(y)\left(y^{a-1}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{-a}}{1+t}\mathrm dt\right)\mathrm dy$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(s-1)!}\int_0^1 \ln^{s-1}(y)\left(y^{a-1}\pi \csc(\pi(1-a))\right)\mathrm dy$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(s-1)!}\pi\csc(a\pi)\int_0^1 \ln^{s-1}(y)\, y^{a-1}\mathrm dy$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(s-1)!}\pi\csc(a\pi)\frac{(-1)^{s-1}(s-1)!}{a^s}$$

$$=-\pi\, a^{-s}\csc(a\pi).$$

---

Using this approach, we also find:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_a(-x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=(2^{-2a}-2^{-a-1})\pi\zeta(a)-a\beta(a+1);$$

$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2a+1}(-x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{4^{-2a}-4^{-a}}{8}\pi\zeta(2a+1)-\frac{2a+1}{2}\beta(2a+2)$$
$$+\sum_{n=0}^a \eta(2a-2n)\beta(2n+2);$$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_a(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=(1-2^{a-1})\pi\zeta(a);$$

$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2a+1}(-x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1-4^a}{2}\pi\zeta(2a+1)+2\sum_{n=0}^a 4^{n}\eta(2a-2n)\beta(2n+2).$$

Answer (score 1):

With $\text{Li}’_s(-x)=\frac{1}x \text{Li}_{s-1}(-x) $, integrate by parts $s$ times

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_s(-x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\mathrm dx \overset{ibp}=- \frac1{\alpha^s }\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-\alpha}}{1+x}dx =-\frac1{\alpha^s}\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi \alpha}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work out the dilogarithmic one. Here is my proof:

1. Changing to a Double Integral

$\displaystyle \text{Li}_2(-x) = -\int_0^{-x}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}dt=-\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+ux)}{u}du \tag{1}$

Plugging (1) into our integral and reversing the order of integration we find

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\text{Li}_2(-x)}{x^{1+\alpha}}dx \\
&=- \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+ux)}{ux^{1+\alpha}}du \ dx \\
&=- \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+u x)}{u x^{1+\alpha}}dx \ du \tag{2}
\end{align*}

2. Simplification of the Inner Integral

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+ux)}{x^{1+\alpha}}dx &= u^{\alpha}\int_0^\infty \frac{t e^t}{(e^t-1)^{1+\alpha}}dt \quad (t=\log(1+ux))\\
&=\frac{u^\alpha}{\alpha} \left[ 0+\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(e^t-1)^\alpha}dt\right] \quad (\text{Integration by Parts}) \\
&=\frac{u^\alpha}{\alpha} \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t}(1-e^{-t})^{-\alpha} dt \\
&= \frac{u^\alpha}{\alpha} \int_0^1 y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{-\alpha} dy \quad (y=e^{-t}) \\
&= \frac{u^\alpha}{\alpha} \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha) \\
&= \frac{u^\alpha}{\alpha} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi \alpha)} \tag{3}
\end{align*}

3. Final Answer
   Using the result (3) in (2) gives us

\begin{align*}
I&=- \int_0^1 \frac{1}{u} \left(\frac{\pi u^\alpha}{\alpha \sin(\pi \alpha)} \right) du \\
&=- \frac{\pi}{\alpha \sin(\pi \alpha)}\int_0^1 u^{\alpha-1}du \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{\alpha^2 \sin(\pi \alpha)}
\end{align*}